# Could this integral be simplified further?

Tags: calculus, integration

Grateful for any guidance on how to further simplify this integral (maybe into hypergeometric functions):

$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\exp \left(\frac{z^2}{4\, t\,(w+1)^2}-\frac{z\, v\, i}{\sqrt{t}\,(w+1)}\right)} {(w+1)^{1+\alpha}}\, dw\\\\$$

The context can be found in [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430227/fractional-partial-derivatives-and-integrals-of-de-bruijns-h-tz-function-d).

Thanks.

Comment: Hm mathematica gives me this
``((1 + w)^(-3 - a) z (-4 i Sqrt[t] v (1 + w) + z))/(4 t)`` when i run fullsimplify and this
``ConditionalExpression[(z (-((4 i Sqrt[t] v)/(1 + a)) + z/(2 + a)))/(
 4 t), Re[a] > -1]`` when integrate

Comment: @Max0815 That outcome doesn't look right to me. Could you share the coded integral that you entered in Mathematica?

Comment: Yea oops nvm i guess i typed it wrong initially bruh